# Google map autocomplete for IOS

Tags: ios, ionic2

i am using google auto complete in my IOS Ionic 2 app. When i start typing an address in a field the matching addresses appear ok in a drop down list but if I select one, the ion-input field is not populated. Could anyone help me how to fix this?

Template:

```
<ion-item>
<ion-input id="journey_from" name="journey_from" type="text" placeholder="" [(ngModel)] = "location"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Component:

```
 ngAfterViewInit(){
    let options = {
      componentRestrictions:{
        country: 'IN'
      },
      types: ['(regions)']
    }
    let input = document.getElementById('autocomplete').getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    let autoComplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.autocomplete.nativeElement,options );
    google.maps.event.addListener(autoComplete,'place_changed', () => {
     this.placeSelect = autoComplete.getPlace();
 this.location= this.placeSelect.formatted_address;

     this.changeDetect.detectChanges();   });
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a form around it and use .updateValueAndValidity from 'angular/forms' ? More info at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html

Comment: Hi @ARD, we're having the same issue. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @S. Roose, I Fixed it by changing the ion-input to normal input.

 <input type = "text"  id = "autocomplete" placeholder="Enter Location" [(ngModel)] = "location" />

Comment: @ARD Thanks for the feedback. Strange enough, I’m already using a normal input. I guess I’m dealing with a different route cause than.